# Where is it better to store image data in react/redux app?

Tags: reactjs, redux

There is an application on React/Redux, which has the functionality to load images through FileReader. After the image is loaded, I get it as dataUrl. So, where is it better to save this data to use it in several React components? To store a relatively large amount of data in the Redux Store seems like a bad idea. At the same time, if the image data is saved somewhere else, the idea "one source of true" breaks. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest creating an [Object URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) instead of a dataUrl, then saving that in the store, as it won't be a huge string anymore. Don't forget to revoke them when you don't need them anymore if possible.

Comment: For anyone just getting here, there is now a medium article that goes over this approach, https://medium.com/@gabriele.cimato/on-how-to-store-an-image-in-redux-d623bcc06ca7

I'm not the author, it just helped me when trying to save an image in non base64 format!

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but just keep in mind that if you're using some persist libraries such as *redux-persist*, the Object URL won't be able to load because it will be revoked as soon as the user refreshes the page, while if you save it in base64 data format you'll be able to load it anyway.